# Removing image overlay over video on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a youtube video with only the image showing http://jsfiddle.net/308dctdd/1/
and the video loads on click.There is a `<span>` element over both `<div>`s that should hide on click. With my code the first `<span>` element does hide but not the second one.

`html`

```
<div class="vid">
   <img id="hide" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Z7JgY9zezj4/hqdefault.jpg" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Z7JgY9zezj4?autoplay=1" />
   <div id="hide1">
     <h3>Johnny Depp<br /><span>Acting Technique</span></h3>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="vid">
   <img id="hide" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Z7JgY9zezj4/hqdefault.jpg" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Z7JgY9zezj4?autoplay=1" />
   <div id="hide1">
     <h3>Johnny Depp<br /><span>Acting Technique</span></h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

`JS`

```
$('img').click(function () {
var video = $('<iframe />', {
    'src': this.dataset.video,
        'height': this.clientHeight,
        'width': this.clientWidth
});
$(this).replaceWith(video);
$('#hide1').hide();
});
```

`css`

```
.vid {
width: 350px;
height: 298px;
float: left;
margin: 20px 25px 70px 70px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 0px -50px;
background-repeat: none;
position: relative;
}
.vid div {
overflow: hidden;
width: 300px;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.32);
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: 10%;
} 
.vid div h3 {
color: black;
font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
max-width: 450px;
padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
}
.vid div h3 span {
color: black;
text-align: center;
width: 300px;
font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 19px;
}
```

Comment: Your ID attributes are not unique!

Comment: Well the videos are generated by a loop so I can't have different id's for each image.

Comment: Then you don't have a valid HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the JS :

```
$('img').click(function () {
$t = $(this).next("#hide1");
var video = $('<iframe />', {
    'src': this.dataset.video,
        'height': this.clientHeight,
        'width': this.clientWidth
    });
    $(this).replaceWith(video);
    $t.hide();
});
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/308dctdd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('#hide1').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```